# Split Single Column into multiple and Load it to a Table or a View

Tags: sql-server, view, merge, split

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have a source table with a few columns (A, B) containing string data to split into a multiple columns. I do have function that does the split already written.

The data from the Source table (the source table format cannot be modified) is used in a View being created. But I need to have my View have already split data for Column A and B from the Source table. So, my view will have extra columns that are not in the Source table.

Then the View populated with the Source table is used to Merge with the Other Table.

**There two questions here:**

1. Can I split column A and B from the Source table when creating a View, but do not change the Source Table?
2. How to use my existing User Defined Function in the View "Select" statement to accomplish this task?

**Idea in short:**

String to split is also shown in the example in the commented out section. Pretty much have Destination table, vStandardizedData View, SP that uses the View data to Merge to tblStandardizedData table. So, in my Source column I have column A and B that I need to split before loading to tblStandardizedData table.

There are five objects that I'm working on:

1. Source File
2. Destination Table
3. vStandardizedData View
4. tblStandardizedData table
5. Stored procedure that does merge
   (Update and Insert) form the vStandardizedData View.

Note: all the 5 objects a listed in the order they are supposed to be created and loaded.

Separately from this there is an existing UDFunction that can split the string which I was told to use

Example of the string in column A (column B has the same format data) to be split:

```
6667 Mission Street, 4567 7rd Street, 65 Sully Pond Park
```

**Desired result:**

[image]

User-defined function returns a table variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Schema].[udfStringDelimeterfromTable]
(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(MAX) -- List of delimited items
  , @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
)   
RETURNS @List TABLE (Item VARCHAR(MAX)) WITH SCHEMABINDING
/* 
* Returns a table of strings that have been split by a delimiter.
* Similar to the Visual Basic (or VBA) SPLIT function. The 
* strings are trimmed before being returned.  Null items are not
* returned so if there are multiple separators between items, 
* only the non-null items are returned.
* Space is not a valid delimiter.
*
* Example:
SELECT * FROM [Schema].[udfStringDelimeterfromTable]('abcd,123, 456, efh,,hi', ',')
*
* Test:
DECLARE @Count INT, @Delim CHAR(10), @Input VARCHAR(128)
SELECT @Count = Count(*) 
    FROM  [Schema].[udfStringDelimeterfromTable]('abcd,123, 456', ',')
PRINT 'TEST 1 3 lines:' + CASE WHEN @Count=3 
              THEN 'Worked' ELSE 'ERROR' END
SELECT @DELIM=CHAR(10)
     , @INPUT = 'Line 1' + @delim + 'line 2' + @Delim
SELECT @Count = Count(*) 
    FROM  [Schema].[udfStringDelimeterfromTable](@Input, @Delim)
PRINT 'TEST 2  LF    :' + CASE WHEN @Count=2 
              THEN 'Worked' ELSE 'ERROR' END
```

Comment: You do not provide enough information: Please poste one (or several, if different structure) example of the string. Most string splitting functions will return a recordset, thus leading to many rows one per each string part. If you need the parts in new columns *side-by-side* you need column captions and some logic which value goes where... Please show some more details!

Comment: Just added some UDF code. The string to split is also shown in the example in the commented out section. Pretty much have Destination table, vStandardizedData View, SP that uses the View data to Merge to tblStandardizedData table. So, in my Source column I have column A and B that I need to split before loading to tblStandardizedData table.

Comment: Sorry, try to think with my head: I have no idea what you need... This UDF will return a **table**. This means you'd have to join it and you will get many rows. But in your question I read *to split into a multiple columns*. Is the delimited data in a decent structure? Do you know the max count of parts within one string? Please provide some actual sample strings and the desired output.

Comment: It could be up to 5 instances of the strings derived from Column A (same is the B). Also Just added example of the string and the desired result. As for the UDFunction it's already written and I was told to use that to to the split. Is it more clear now?

Comment: There are five objects that I'm working on:1) Source File 2) Destination Table 3) vStandardizedData View 4) tblStandardizedData table 5) Stored Procedure that does Merge (Update and Insert) form the vStandardizedData View. Note: all the 5 objects a listed in the order they are supposed to be created and loaded. Separately from this there  is an existing UDFunction that can split the string which I was told to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd ask you, is to [read this: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In general: If you use your UDF, you'll get *table-wise* data. It was best, if your UDF would return the item together with a running number. Otherwise you'll first need to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)` to create a part number in order to create your target column names via string concatenation. Then use `PIVOT` to get the columns *side-by-side*.

An easier approach could be a string split via XML like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275075/5089204)

A quick proof of concept to show the principles:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,YourValues VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'6667 Mission Street, 4567 7rd Street, 65 Sully Pond Park')
,(2,'Other addr1, one more addr, and another one, and even one more');

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourValues,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS AsXml
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AsXml.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS Address1
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AsXml.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS Address2
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AsXml.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS Address3
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AsXml.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS Address4
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(AsXml.value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS Address5
FROM Casted
```

If your values might include forbidden characters (especially `<,> and &`) you can find an approach to deal with this in the linked answer.

The result

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
| ID | Address1            | Address2        | Address3           | Address4          | Address5 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
| 1  | 6667 Mission Street | 4567 7rd Street | 65 Sully Pond Park | NULL              | NULL     |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
| 2  | Other addr1         | one more addr   | and another one    | and even one more | NULL     |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
```